# autocomplete JQUERY no muestra datos si no están en orden

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

Estoy usando autocomplete de jQuery. Tengo un problema al mostrar los datos relacionados al teclear en mi input.

Realizo una llamada ajax en donde obtengo una respuesta en mi base de datos. En mi consulta a mi base de datos uso `like %%` para buscar criterios no importando el orden. Por ejemplo tengo un dato de mi columna *descripcion_producto*, en donde tengo "producto mermelada de fresa roja". si tecleo en mi input: "producto roja" mi consulta funciona perfectamente y lo obtengo en mi respuesta. Cuando coloco "producto" sí muestra las coincidencias pero cuando coloco "producto roja" como que el autocomplete ya no encuentra el dato y no muestra nada. Pero como repito en mi respuesta a mi base de datos sí encuentra el dato:

Aquí muestro mi solicitud ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "ajax/productos.ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                'accion': 6,
                'valorInput': valorInput
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta);

                //input iptCodigoVenta que lo autocomplete
                $("#iptCodigoVenta").autocomplete({

                        source: respuesta,
                        //minLength: 3, // Mínimo de 3 caracteres antes de buscar
                        select: function(event, ui) {

                            CargarProductos(ui.item.value);

                            return false;
                        }
                    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                        return $("<li class ='ui-autocomplete-row'></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append(item.label)
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    }
```

y esta es mi consulta a mi base de datos:

```
static public function mdlListarNombreProductos($valorInput)
    {
        $palabras = explode(" ", $valorInput); // Divide el valor de entrada en palabras

        // Inicializa la parte de la consulta SQL
                                $sql = "SELECT
                                            codigo_producto,
                                            c.nombre_categoria,
                                            descripcion_producto,
                                            p.precio_venta_producto,
                                            p.stock_producto,
                                            foto
                                        FROM
                                            productos p
                                        INNER JOIN
                                            categorias c ON p.id_categoria_producto = c.id_categoria
                                        WHERE ";

        // Crea una lista de condiciones para cada palabra
        $condiciones = array();
        foreach ($palabras as $index => $palabra) {
            $condiciones[] = "descripcion_producto LIKE :valorInput" . $index;
            $condiciones[] = "stock_producto > 0" . $index;
        }

        // Combina las condiciones con "AND"
        $sql .= implode(" AND ", $condiciones);

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);

        // Enlaza cada palabra individual con comodines
        foreach ($palabras as $index => $palabra) {
            $stmt->bindValue(':valorInput' . $index, '%' . $palabra . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $productos = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí ya no muestra la coincidencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en la respuesta sí obtengo correctamente la coincidencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si usas postgresql puedes usar SIMILARITY pero si usas mysql debes buscar por coincidencias separadas, puede que estes armando mal la query, escapa a query para que verifiques si estas llamando bien la consulta

Comment: la consulta funciona bien, ya que como puedes ver en el codigo coloco un console.log(respuesta) para ver que dato me trae, y efectivamente cuando coloco "producto roja" en mi input, si obtengo el dato en formato json: value: '351654231 / Arroz / PRODUCTO MERMELADA ROJA / 20 / 555'. Mi autocomplete funciona bien ya que cuando coloco en mi input: "producto" si muestra las opciones relacionadas con lo que tiene descripcion de producto, per cuando coloco "producto roja" ya no me muestra las opciones, ya que en mi bd lo tengo como "producto mermelada roja"